Why is Godot not finding a node?
I am trying to make a health bar above an enemy in the game I am working on. I want to access the TextureProgressBar node to change the value to the enemy's health. My node tree looks like this:

I am trying to access TextureProgressBar from Path2D with the path "Control/TextureProgressBar" I get the error: @ _process(): Node not found: "Control/TextureProgressBar" (relative to "/root/world/Enemy/Path2D"). I have tried defining the node as a variable in @onready but that also did not work. I have also tried having the Control node be a child of Enemy and used the path "../Control/TextureProgressBar".
The relevant code looks like this:
var health_bar = get_node("Control/TextureProgressBar")
health_bar.value = health```


This is working fine for me in a new Godot 4.3 project. Is there more to your node tree?
